# Site footer is shaky on my mobile device

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

My website http://galnova.com/ has just been given a responsive upgrade. It is fine on browsers but when I look at it on my samsung device the page wont scroll and it shakes like crazy. I could not find any error in the footer class or the structure itself but I am curious to why this is happening.

```
<footer>
<div class="wrap">
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en_US"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work by <a xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" href="http://www.galnova.com" property="cc:attributionName" rel="cc:attributionURL">Keith Jeter</a> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en_US">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported License</a>.<!--<br />Based on a work at <a xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://www.galnova.com" rel="dct:source">http://www.galnova.com</a>.-->

<p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
<p>&copy; 2015 Galaxy Supernova &middot; <!--<a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a>--></p>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Which device and browser specifically is this happening on? Have any other mobile devices been tested?

Comment: It happens on my android for both opera and chrome mobile and only in vertical orientation.

Comment: To be more clear, what is the _specific_ device (i.e. Samsung Galaxy S6) or devices you have tested, and have you confirmed that it works fine on any other mobile devices? Thanks.

Comment: It would also be useful to know if just one page or all pages on your site exhibit this problem.

Comment: I have tested it on the samsung galaxy note 4 and the iphone 4s and the iphone 6. It's broken on all three.

Comment: Did you happen to see the possible solution posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a defined height to your footer and report back with any effects.

Like so:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    footer {
    border-radius: 0!important;
    border: none!important;
    margin: 0!important;
    height: 400px;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Disregard the above; the problem is coming from the Pirobox overlay plugin. From a CSS perspective, a quick fix I noticed is to add `overflow: hidden` to the `.piro_html` class in the [Pirobox stylesheet you reference](http://galnova.com/pirobox_extended/css_pirobox/style_1/style.css), like so:

```
.piro_html {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 150001;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Doing this causes you to lose the little "X" closure box, but since you can tap anywhere on the exposed body copy to escape the lightbox, that seems to be an acceptable and clean solution. You could also look into playing with the jQuery code.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: When you open up the site in Chrome Dev Tools and test mobile devices, you can tell that something is preventing scrolling to the bottom of the footer. I noticed that there were some hidden elements at the bottom and deleted them. The problem stopped. So then all that was left was to go back and try out a couple CSS options. I noticed that some weird height and width things were happening and adjusting the overflow is often a solution to stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you! This has been a helpful excersise